# How can I change the borders of mask div?

Tags: mask, gxt

How can I change the borders of Mask div ?, I am using 3.0.6 gxt.

```
final Portlet portlet = new Portlet();
portlet.mask("Loading Requests ....");
```

I want to add the style to say not to show any borders in the mask div, how to do that ?

I tried to override ext-all.js with my css, but didn't work (hoping x-mask & x-mask-msg are the css class names  )

```
.x-mask {
border: 0px solid #a3bad9 !important;
}


.x-mask div {
border: 0px solid #a3bad9 !important;
}


.x-mask-msg {
border: 0px solid #a3bad9 !important;
}


.x-mask-msg div {
border: 0px solid #a3bad9 !important;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to create an appearance.  Here is Sencha's guide to doing that in gxt 3: https://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/concepts/appearance/Appearance_3.html

The appearance that you'll want to override should be Css3MaskAppearance.  I'm not sure which part of the .css it will go in, I'm guessing .mask or .box but you should be able to add borders: 0px; and they should disappear.